# node cached export object is broken

Tags: node.js, require

I'm requiring an module that has already been required in another file, but when I get the object, many of it's keys are undefined. A bunch of the keys are there, but some are not, even after I call some of the exposed functions. If I console.log the object, the keys look like they are there.

Example:

```
var mod = require('myModule')
console.log(mod) // { 'aKey':[Function], 'doStoff':[Function] }
console.log(mod.aKey) // undefined
mod.doStoff() // calls 'aKey' 
//TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'aKey'
//this error is thrown inside myModule
```

This would not overly surprise me if this module was doing something goofy when it get's loaded, but the module has already been loaded and I have used it for several things already in the main js file.

The only thing I can think of that is off the norm: I've required this module in the main js file (and it works), but the place that it does not work is inside a module that is required in the main.

To be clearer->

- main.js requires myModule
- main.js requires otherModule
- otherModule requires myModule

myModule was installed by npm, but I'm prototyping the otherModule in place in the node_modules folder until I get it put up somewhere so npm will install it.

I don't see why this would cause a problem; I thought that the object that gets returned from require gets kept in the require cache--as is--so that when it gets required any time afterwards you get that same object. It seems that my object has been partially deleted or something.

What is causing this? What should I do differently?

Comment: Are you certain there are no circular dependencies?  `require`'d modules are cached, but in the case of circular dependencies node will first return an "unfinished copy" of the module still being loaded.  See http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

Comment: I'm sure there are no circular dependancies. I think that, even in the case of circular dependancies, if the object was finished once, it would not revert to unfinished.

Comment: Few things I'd check: 1) does `otherModule` modifies, in any way, `myModule`? 2) Is it possible that `myModule`'s path is resolved to a different string when `require`d from a different module? 3) Does `myModule` do anything async when required? Of course, it would be easier if I could see the code.

Comment: I am certain that `myModule` does not get changed. You can see the module I am requiring [here](https://github.com/JoshRagem/QCNode). The code on github has a lot of `qc.whatever = function(){..};exports.whatever = qc.whatever` and if I just set `qc = exports` the problem goes away. I'm not sure what I am misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found why I was having these issues:

When node tries to resolve the path for `require('myModule'`, it will walk down the directory path *from the position of the current module*. If you have a symbolic link as a directory in your node_modules folder, nodejs will not follow that link back to your own node_modules folder--it will just walk down the directory path looking for your module. I had a symbolic link in there to help me keep my modules that are under development in a place I could easily test them. I'm not sure at what point I put that link in, but I didn't think it was important.

Since the `require` did not resolve to the same path for me, I kept getting a fresh load of the module, instead of the one in the require cache.

I am not sure why I got the symptoms I did originally (with certain keys being missing sometimes), but since I had a broken setup I guess I found some unexpected behavior.